# How to write Windows ETW logs with golang?

Tags: windows, go, etw

I see there are go packages for collecting ETW logs. But seems no package to write ETW logs. Especially no package using TraceLoggingWrite APIs to implement. Anyone is aware of packages or easy way to do it? Suppose the last way is using cgo to wrap a c function to do it.

Go etw package seems pretty limited on reading ETW logs. But no function to write. So are other packages like 0xrawsec/golang-etw.